# Test 'InvokeWebService' exceeded execution timeout period

Tags: c#, unit-testing

How do I increase the default execution timeout for my unit tests? I have a unit test which calls a web service. It often runs for longer than 10 seconds, which produces a timeout error. I'm using Visual Studio Team System 2008.

Comment: Could you paste the code of the test and clarify which bit causes the timeout error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a bunch of different ways to control the timeouts of unit tests in visual Studio.  See this article for guidance:  [How to: Set Time Limits for Running Tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243175.aspx).  (The article is written for 2010, but I verified that the settings exist in 2008 as well.)

As an aside, calling a real Web Service from a unit test is generally not recommended.  You would be better off using a mocking framework (like Rhino Mocks) and [dependency inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) to construct your code in such a way that you can test without requiring a connection to a real service.